# android multiple videoView problem, Galaxy Tab specific

Tags: android, tabs, android-videoview, galaxy

I am having problems with multiple videoViews specifically on Galaxy Tab.

In my app, I have two different video files which I want to play simultaneously. So I designed my app to have two videoViews side by side. Tried to run it on two non Galaxy tabs and it worked. Easy as that.

But then, I tried to test it on my Galaxy Tab and the problem comes out. The two video file doesn't play. At some point, the first video file plays and then stops and pops up the Cannot Play Video error. I spent almost two days looking for the cause of the problem and I failed. That's why I resorted to guessing what could be the cause.

My suspicion was that it cannot render two videos at the same time, so I tried to play only the sound of the first file using MediaPlayer and play the other one in the videoView. And I think my suspicioin was right because it works, the first video file plays only the sound, and the other one plays the full video and the sound.

I am looking for someone with this kind of problem, or someone who knows a workaround for this. I will post my simple code here for you to take a look at it. I would really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

junmats.

```
final videoView v1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
final videoView v2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2); 

   Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Uri uriFile = Uri.parse(myFile);
            v1.setVideoURI(uriFile);
            v1.start();
        }
    });
    th1.start();

    Thread th2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Uri uriFile = Uri.parse(
            v2.setVideoURI(uriFile);
                  v2.start();
        }
    });
    th2.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be dependent on the kernel version so it may not be supported on certain devices... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17802

You may have to wait for an update.